# Corona sensor object not removing properly

Tags: android, ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk

I have a group of objects within a game that is a sensor(let's call them collectively object1). When it collides with my main object (object2), the score increments by 10. However, after each subsequent restart of the scene(not the whole game), each collision between object1 and object2 duplicates itself, then triplicates and so forth.

So for the first running of the scene, object1 collides with object2 once(I know this because I have a print statement every time the 2 objects collide). The second time it collides twice, the third time three times and so forth. I presume I am not removing a certain feature of the sensor but I cannot figure out what it is. How do I correctly remove the objects if this is the problem?

My code for the removal of object1 on collision:

```
local function onCollision( self,event )

        if(event.object2.name == "bonus")then--if we hit a bonus ball

            event.object2:removeSelf()--removes the bonus ball object from the scene
            print("bonus collided")

            display.remove(event.object2)


            game.addToScore(10)--adds a value of 10 to the score
            scoreText.text = game.returnScore()
            Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.object2)

        else                

            composer.gotoScene("restart")   
            Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", onObjectTouch)    
        end

    end
```

Comment: Are you creating your display objects in scene:create or scene:show? You should create them in scene:create, which will only be called once. scene:show will be called every time you enter the scene.

Comment: Yes the objects get created in the scene:create.

Comment: I'm seeing a couple of error in the current code but not sure if it causes your error:
1. event.object2:removeSelf() and display.remove( event.object2 ) does the same thing
2. `Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", onObjectTouch)` might not be called because you're calling `gotoScene` on the line before
3. `Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", event.object2)` should remove a function, not a display object
4. Maybe 2 and 3 are switched?

Could you post the completed code so that I can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied your code and in short this is the problem

```
ball.collision = onCollision
```

It's located under `scene:show` and therefore a new eventListener will be created each time that you to the scene. And it's not being removed under `scene:hide`.

Basically half of your code doesn't really do anything. For exampel you remove the same item twice, add Runtime listeners to objects (not functions) and you're trying to remove thise Runtime listeners. For example this tries to remove a Runtime event listener on a display object that doesn't even exist:

```
Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", circle )
```

What you need to do is:

- Create all objects and listeners under `scene:create`
- Use local collision handling (i.e. not Runtime listeners): https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#local-collision-handling
- Rewrite your code so that you have functions and listeners outside of the `scene:create`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to corona and am trying it out for a college project for the first time. I will rewrite the code as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, my intention was not to sound harsh as I know how hard it can be to write good-looking code and I think Lua (Corona) makes it even easier to write bad code because it still works, if that makes sense :)

Comment: Yes exactly! I didn't think there was any reason to be too strict since it still all worked quite well. Thanks for your help!